# server 2008 volume backup over unc patch error "could not create one of the files" fails

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

using server 2008 32bit std edition to do a backup of a drive to another computer on the domain using the unc path.

backup starts then fails with error about "can't create one of the files"
really disappointed in the backup strat that is in server 08, should of just stuck with server 2003 r2.

any ideas?
thanks.
gd

Comment: ok, error seems to be only with one of the volumes, is there any chance that win 2008 does not support some some of raid setups?

Comment: i will eventually get to using server 08 for backup, when i do and iron out the issues i will post what or how i did it. right now i am using another server to mount the backup, close open sessions of files and then do a backup without shadow copy. this works fine since it makes a bkf that we all are probably accustomed to. as well if it is corrupt you can always use recovery methods to fix the bkf file. looking at the vhd file format you have to wonder that microsoft did this in order to allow boot using vhd from a custom bootloader that mounts vhd files and creates another boot option entry.

Comment: this is what i am doing for now. i have previous copies or shadow copies 3x per day. i have client plug in removable hdd, we choose previous version, copy and dump to the hdd external. we walk off with the data. preserves security blah blah blah. this is a dirty fix for now. just thought i would post in case anyone else was looking for quick fix. this works well for us since this is a file server only and is a member server of domain so i don't need anything fancy for offsite disaster, just something that has all their data in case of fire etc.gd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server 2008 Backup doesn't officially support scheduling backups to network shares.

It sucks I know.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770266(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Just because it's not supported, doesn't mean it doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have SQL2008 or Exchange 2010 installed. Odd I know.